# KSQL for distinct values

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

How do I check if there are more than two records in a stream that are from the same userId but with a different productId. Lets say we have stream (uid,pid,price) I want to emit if from the same uid there are multiple different pid.  What is the correct query syntax if pid is a string?

Answer (score 0):

use count_distinct operator

```
 SELECT COUNT_DISTINCT(PID), uid
 FROM product_stream WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 5 SECONDS) GROUP BY uid
 HAVING COUNT_DISTINCT(PID) > 1 EMIT CHANGES;
```